# Can I change the DDEV default database version for Drupal?

Tags: database, config, ddev

When I run `ddev config` to create a new `drupal10` project, the created `config.yaml` file contains

```yaml
name: drupal
type: drupal10
docroot: web
php_version: "8.1"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
    type: mariadb
    version: "10.4"
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
```

Is there a way to make it so that the default database version when running the command is

```yaml
database:
    type: mariadb
    version: "10.11"
```

Essentially, I don't want to have to manually set the database version in the config.yaml file each time I create a project.

I tried changing `~/.ddev/global_config.yaml` to have that as well, but that didn't change the behavior. I guess it's not a valid global setting? If I forget to change the DB version during project setup, then I have to drop the database, reconfigure, and re-setup the database to have the newer 10.11 version. I'd like to be able to set the default.

Comment: RTFM: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/#database-backends-and-defaults , and https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/database-types/   "The default database type is MariaDB, and the default version is currently 10.4....", and (when I am correctly reading it)  info on how to change the default database type and/or default version.

Comment: @Luuk That doesn't answer the question. I know how to configure my site to a specific DB version by manually editing config.yaml after running the command. What I want to configure in this situation is what database version is set by default when running `ddev config`. That's completely different. Please read my question again. I'm not new to DDEV; I've been using it for a few years.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to make that clearer.

Comment: Build it yourself, after changing this file: https://github.com/ddev/ddev/blob/master/pkg/nodeps/mariadb_values.go  (I do mean this line: `const MariaDBDefaultVersion = MariaDB104`(

Comment: Thanks for opening https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/5693 - also related https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/5696